# Spring relationships between tables in view

Tags: spring, eclipselink

Well, I started a new project using **Spring MVC** (**I'm beginner in technology**) and soon I had a basic question which I am unable to find on the internet, maybe the reason that I'm doing wrong or implementing the wrong question.

I have a form in which the data will be persisted are in two different tables.

What better way to do this?

I created two related tables, one called "Agency" and another called "Login". An "Agency" may contain one or more "Login" (@ OneToMany), but the problem takes the view creation time, because data from both tables will compose a single form. With some research I noticed that I can not have two modelAttribute in my form.

I apologize for the mistakes in English.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

if the mapping is correct and Agency contain one or many login, what you have to do is render the Agency in the model and view and in your form iterate the logins

```
   <form:form id="foo"
           method="post"
           action="url"
           modelAttribute="agency">

        <form:input type="hidden" path="id"/>

                <c:forEach var="login" items="${agency.logins}"
                           varStatus="login_index">
                        <form:input type="hidden" path="login.id" />
                </c:foreach>
    </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply.

But is not it :(

I have a form in which the data will be persisted are in two different tables.

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="addAgency">  
    <div class="input-group">  
        <span class="input-group-addon entypo-user"></span> 
            //Table Agency
            <spring:bind path="tenant.firstName"/>  
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Nome"/>
            //Table Login
            <spring:bind path="login.email"/>  
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Nome"/>  
    </div>  

                             //Rest of my form... 

                      </form>
```

In my view I have the annotation "bind" Spring, searching in the internet I found this way to make the connection between the controller and the view for persist two tables.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
    public String home(@ModelAttribute("tenant") Agency tenant, @ModelAttribute("login") Login login, ModelMap map) {  

        Agency agency = dashboardFacade.getAgency();  
        map.addAttribute("agency", agency);  


        if (tenantResolver.isMasterTenant()) {
            //Here is the problem!!  
            // Add an attribute in my view of type login and agency, but i don't kwon if it is correct.
            map.addAttribute("tenant", tenant);  
            map.addAttribute("login", login);  
            return "landing/index";  

        } else {  

            return "dashboard/home";  
        }  
    }
```

The method below to save an agency and login.

```
// Add a new agency  
@RequestMapping(value = "/addAgency", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
public String addAgency(@ModelAttribute("tenant") Agency agency, @ModelAttribute("login") Login login, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {  
    agency = dashboardFacade.addAgency(agency);  
    login = dashboardFacade.addLogin(login);  
    return "redirect:" + getAgencyFullUrl(agency);  
}
```

What better way to do this?

Thank you